# Copy Paste Vector Attributes and Features between layers in QGIS

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

Hello everyone i am new to QGIS but i was given a task on it about creating a python plugin for it. So to complete my task i need to make a temporarly copy of a layer inside the algorithm but based on what i found online it seems like the temporary layer doesn't want to copy any features or attributes from the original layer.

I tried to implaiment the code as it follows :

```
#rest of the code

#Original layer
original_layer = QgsVectorLayer(input_file_path, "Original Layer", "ogr")
#Add the temporary layer to the project
temp_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "Output_layer", "memory")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp_layer)

#Copy features and attributes
features = []
attributes = []

for feature in original_layer.getFeatures():
attribute = feature.attributes()
attributes.append(attribute)
features.append(feature)

temp_layer.startEditing()
data_provider = temp_layer.dataProvider()
data_provider.addAttributes(attributes)
data_provider.addFeatures(features)
temp_layer.commitChanges()

#rest of the code
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't want to copy"? What is the behaviour you are observing, does it not do anything, or do you get an error, or some other unexpected behaviour? In addition: what is "the algorithm?" could you give a little bit more context about that? Could you also please use appropriate spacing in your code, as it is now hard to see what is or isn't in your for loop.

in addition, please check out this thread on the gis.stackexchange which I think contains a possible solution to your question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205947/duplicating-layer-in-memory-using-pyqgis